# Symfony 3. 4 Unrecognized field: emailCanonical

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony 3.4 and was tasked to add a password reset feature to an exsting website. I have followed a tutorial on using friendsofsymfony/user-bundle and got up to the point where i am sending a Json request to my controler and it responds back :

```
{"code":500,"message":"Unrecognized field: emailCanonical"}
```

The line causing the problem is:

```
$user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);
```

This is the complete file src/AppBundle/RestPasswordManagementController.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseNullableUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;

/**
 * @Annotations\Prefix("password")
 * @RouteResource("/password", pluralize=false)
 */
class RestPasswordManagementController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{

    /**
     * @Annotations\Post("/reset/request")
     */
    public function requestResetAction(Request $request)
    {

        $username = $request->get('email');        

        /** @var $user UserInterface */
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

            return new JsonResponse(
                $user,
                JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN
            );

        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        /* Dispatch init event */
        $event = new GetResponseNullableUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_SEND_EMAIL_INITIALIZE, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }
        if (null === $user) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                'User not recognised',
                JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN
            );
        }
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_REQUEST, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }
        if ($user->isPasswordRequestNonExpired($this->container->getParameter('fos_user.resetting.token_ttl'))) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                $this->get('translator')->trans('resetting.password_already_requested', [], 'FOSUserBundle'),
                JsonResponse::HTTP_FORBIDDEN
            );
        }
        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
            /** @var $tokenGenerator \FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface */
            $tokenGenerator = $this->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
            $user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }
        /* Dispatch confirm event */
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_SEND_EMAIL_CONFIRM, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }
        $this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendResettingEmailMessage($user);
        $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
        /* Dispatch completed event */
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_SEND_EMAIL_COMPLETED, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }
        return new JsonResponse(
            $this->get('translator')->trans(
                'resetting.check_email',
                [ '%tokenLifetime%' => floor($this->container->getParameter('fos_user.resetting.token_ttl') / 3600) ],
                'FOSUserBundle'
            ),
            JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
        );
    }
    /**
     * Reset user password
     * @Annotations\Post("/reset/confirm")
     */
    public function confirmResetAction(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->request->get('token', null);
        if (null === $token) {
            return new JsonResponse('You must submit a token.', JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.resetting.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);
        if (null === $user) {
            return new JsonResponse(
            // no translation provided for this in \FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController
                sprintf('The user with "confirmation token" does not exist for value "%s"', $token),
                JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
            );
        }
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_INITIALIZE, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }
        $form = $formFactory->createForm([
            'csrf_protection'    => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ]);
        $form->setData($user);
        $form->submit($request->request->all());
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return $form;
        }
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS, $event);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                $this->get('translator')->trans('resetting.flash.success', [], 'FOSUserBundle'),
                JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
            );
        }
        // unsure if this is now needed / will work the same
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return new JsonResponse(
            $this->get('translator')->trans('resetting.flash.success', [], 'FOSUserBundle'),
            JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
        );
    }
    /**
     * Change user password
     *
     * @ParamConverter("user", class="AppBundle:User")
     *
     * @Annotations\Post("/{user}/change")
     */
    public function changeAction(Request $request, UserInterface $user)
    {
        if ($user !== $this->getUser()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
        }
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_INITIALIZE, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');
        $form = $formFactory->createForm([
            'csrf_protection'    => false
        ]);
        $form->setData($user);
        $form->submit($request->request->all());
        if ( ! $form->isValid()) {
            return $form;
        }
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, $event);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                $this->get('translator')->trans('change_password.flash.success', [], 'FOSUserBundle'),
                JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
            );
        }
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return new JsonResponse(
            $this->get('translator')->trans('change_password.flash.success', [], 'FOSUserBundle'),
            JsonResponse::HTTP_OK
        );
    }
}
```

The longin form is not using the same Bundle. Just is case this could help, heres the file: src/AppBundle/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Form\LoginForm;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    private $formFactory;
    private $em;
    private $router;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, EntityManager $em, RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $isLoginSubmit = $request->getPathInfo() == '/login' && $request->isMethod('POST');
        if (!$isLoginSubmit) {
            // skip authentication
            return;
        }

        $form = $this->formFactory->create(LoginForm::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $data = $form->getData();
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $data['_username']
        );

        return $data;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $username = $credentials['_username'];

        return $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $username]);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $password = $credentials['_password'];

        if ($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('security_login');
    }

    protected function getDefaultSuccessRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('app-dashboard');
    }
}
```

As for the view, it's pretty straight forward. Theres a jQuery script that toggle between the login form and the lost password.

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{# -- PAGE TITLE --  #}
{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{# -- PAGE CONTENT --  #}
{% block body %}

    <div class="account-pages"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-page">

        <div class="account-bg">
            <div class="card-box m-b-0">
                <div class="text-xs-center">
                    <a href="/" class="logo">
                        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/app/login-logo.png') }}" alt="SSTenligne">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="m-t-10 p-20 login_form">

                    {{ form_start(form, {'autocomplete': 'off'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(form._username) }}
                        {{ form_row(form._password) }}

                        <div class="form-group text-center row m-t-30">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">{{ 'Login'|trans }}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}

                    <a class="mdp_resset" href="#">Mot de passe perdu?</a>

                </div>

                <div class="m-t-10 p-20 password_resset">

                    {{ form_start(form2, {'autocomplete': 'off'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(form2._username_resset) }}

                        <div class="form-group text-center row m-t-30">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btnResset btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">{{ 'Récupération'|trans }}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {{ form_end(form2) }}

                    <a class="mdp_login" href="#">Retour</a>

                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end card-box-->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper page -->

{% endblock %}


{# -- SPECIFIC SCRIPTS --  #}
{% block scripts %}

    <script>
        {% if error %}
            toastr.error('{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}');
        {% endif %}

        $(".password_resset form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "password/reset/request",
                data:{
                    email:$("#resset_form__username_resset").val()
                },
                error: function (jql, code, returnMsgError) {
                    alert('Une erreur est survenue');
                },
                success: function ($data) {
                    alert('It\'s posted!');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The request is posted to password/reset/request and thats where I get error message:

{"code":500,"message":"Unrecognized field: emailCanonical"}

I am really new to Symfony and don't know where to start to debug this problem. Any help would be geatly appreciated. If you need me to show more code to help me find a solution le me know and I will edit.

EDIT:
So as sugested in the comments, I started to implement a custom Canonicalizer

In my services.yml i added

```
app.my_canonicalizer:
    class: AppBundle\Util\MyCanonicalizer
    arguments: ['@normalize_service']
    public: false
```

In my config I added

```
# FOS User
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: api
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        "[my_email]"
        sender_name:    "[my_name]"
    service:
        mailer: user.mailer.rest
        email_canonicalizer:    app.my_canonicalizer
        username_canonicalizer: app.my_canonicalizer
```

And then created a files called: AppBundle/Util/MyCanonicalizer.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Util;

use FOS\UserBundle\Util\CanonicalizerInterface;

class MyCanonicalizer implements CanonicalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizeService;

    public function __construct(NormalizeService $normalizeService)
    {
        $this->normalizeService = $normalizeService;
    }

    public function canonicalize($string)
    {
        if (null === $string) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->normalizeService->normalize($string);
    }
}
?>
```

And when i send a request i now got this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service &quot;fos_user.util.email_canonicalizer&quot; has a dependency on a non-existent service &quot;normalize_service&quot;. in /home/website/public_html/intranet/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 /home/website/public_html/intranet/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AbstractRecursivePass.php(60): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass-&gt;processValue(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference), false)
#1 /home/website/public_html/intranet/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(28): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AbstractRecursivePass-&gt;processValue(Array, false)
#2 /home/website/public_html/intranet/vendor/sym in <b>/home/website/public_html/intranet/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
```

Comment: I don't use symphony but maybe: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/canonicalizer.html ... when things are referenced that are not present in the code, assume you are missing code (bundle)?

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. I tryed implementing it and got an error. See the edit above

Comment: So dependency hell... Maybe just need to get proper version? (what I linked I think is out of date, but is the crux of your issue I think) Try https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle ? Also, This one made me chuckle: https://jolicode.github.io/fosuserbundle-conf/#/

Comment: Looks like I am already at the last version. And btw, jolicode made me smile haha

Comment: The FOS User entity has a property called emailCanonical.  It's just one example of FOS over-engineering as it contains a case-insensitive copy of email.  It's normally never exposed and there is certainly no need for a custom Canonicalizer.  All I can say is that your approach seems far too complicated.

Comment: Thx Cerad, I think i will start working with the bundles already installed in the projet and see what I can come up with. Seems like symfony has a lot of bundle constraint that are hard to work arround when you start adding them together. Can you post your sugestion as an anwser and i will accept it. Thanks a lot for your time!